# How to create a Makefile that finds files across multiple directories and puts the object files into a different directory?

Tags: c++, c, makefile, gnu-make

I'm a beginner in Makefiles and what I want to do is pretty complicated and if someone can help me then please consider to also explain me how things work so I can learn and understand. Of course I made my research and I wasn't able to find something that will help. So we have the following project:

```
src
 | File1.cpp
 | File2.cpp
 | File3.cpp
src2
 | File4.cpp
 | File5.cpp
 | File6.cpp
obj
Makefile
```

So I want a Makefile that will be able to let my choose as many directories as I want to search for source code files (and this case `src1` and `src2` and then, put the generated object files into one directory (in this case `obj`). So yeah that or something similar or whatever possible you can make... haha, got it? `make` aaaaaah ok I'll stop...

Comment: I guess, this is something you are looking for: https://www.owsiak.org/fortran-and-gnu-make/

Comment: See http://make.mad-scientist.net/papers/

Comment: Unclear. You want to chose what folder needs to be build upon invocation, is that it?

Comment: @kebs YES! That's what I will prefer cause it's more flexible but having it search every sub-directory will also be ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass variable to your makefile using the syntax:

```
$ make SOMEVAR=SOMEVALUE
```

This can be used to pass the folder you want to build:

```
$ make SRC=src1    # or src, src2, ...
```

The makefile can be something like this
(you only mentioned obj file, so I only added that):

```
SRC_FILES=$(wildcard $(SRC)/*.cpp)
OBJ_FILES=$(patsubst $(SRC)/%.cpp,obj/%.o, $(SRC_FILES))

all:$(OBJ_FILES)
    @echo "done!"    

obj/%.o:$(SRC)/%.cpp
    @echo "building $@"
    @$(CXX) -o $@ -c $< $(CFLAGS)
```